# Oracle Enterprise Manager 12c Cloud: Cannot secure agent mid-installation

Tags: oracle-12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

Oracle support isn't being much help currently, so figured I would turn to you all. I am installing OEM in my Solaris 10 test environment. I have almost finished installing the OMS, but it bombs when it attempts to secure the agent. The log advises me to secure it manually. Securing the agent with `emctl secure agent` fails. Errors from various logs include the following:

gcagent.log:

```
WARN - Ping communication error
o.s.emSDK.agent.comm.exception.ConnectException [Failure connecting to https://[domain]:1159/empbs/upload/ , err ]
java.lang.NullPointerException [null]
```

emctl.log

```
Status output: Status agent Failure:Unable to connect to the agent at https://[domain]:3872/emd/lifecycle/main/ [Connection refused]
```

secure.log

```
openPage.834 - Opening: https://[domain]:1159/empbs/genwallet
main.260 - Failed to secure the Agent:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Troubleshooting with emctl pingOMS reveals the following message:

```
EMD pingOMS error: Failure connecting to https://[domain]:1159/empdbs/upload , err
```

I was hoping that the error message would give me a clue as to what is going on, but the error message is blank. In the support documents I've seen, there is always a message here that would help diagnose the problem but no such luck. Any assistance would be appreciated; let me know if any other information would be useful.

Comment: Looks like a firewall problem to me. Have you opened the ports?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; was on holiday. I also see I left out some critical information in my rush at the end of the day. Currently, the agent is simply trying to contact the OMS, which is on the same zone. I've also confirmed with our firewall team that none of the above activity is hitting our firewall. Not sure if there's something in Solaris 10 that is interfering with port access?